# Routing websockets to socket.io with haproxy on multiple ports

Tags: websocket, socket.io, haproxy

I'm having a great problem correctly routing socket.io websocket handshake using haproxy on a ubuntu server i'm trying to configure. I've read a lot both here and on the web but i can't seem to find a conclusive solution.
What i have to achieve is pretty complicated.
I have more than one istance of nodejs running on the same server, each one on different ports, but i have to be able to reach all of them on port 80 from the browser ( clients firewall problems).
What i managed to achieve is rewriting with haproxy from

```
http://HOST/8081/
```

to

```
http://HOST:8081/
```

on the backend, so that every request will be router to the correct nodejs istance.
I have now encountered a problem with sockets, since for haproxy to rewrite every request, i have to use httpclose as an option, but this makes websockets fail.
Searching i found a workaround, routing requests that started with /socket.io or /node to the same backend with the right port, but with different options.
That worked, but now all the websockets requests are linked to the same nodejs istance, and that obviously is a problem, since all clients now connect to one single server.
I've tried all i could to create and acl to send the websockets to the right server, but i can't find anything in the request to route them.
Here is the last configuration that i managed to achieve, with this one the websocket request get routed to the right server, but the websocket fails to create and socket.io fallback to xhr-polling, the error on the browser is

> WebSocket connection to ws://HOST/socket.io/1/websocket/Wra1vIqoPcTqBNkRLTif' failed: Unexpected response code: 503

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    # httpclose is necessary otherwise haproxy will rewrite only the first request of     the session
    option httpclose
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout 5000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000

frontend http
    bind :80
    option  forwardfor
    acl is_socket_io path_beg /node
    acl is_socket_io path_beg /socket.io
    #use_backend socket_io if is_socket_io
    acl myacl_rewrite0 hdr(host) -i HOST
    acl myacl_path0 path_dir -i 8081
    acl myacl_referer0 hdr_beg(referer) http://HOST/8081/
    use_backend socket_io_8081 if is_socket_io myacl_referer0
    use_backend mysrv_rewrite0 if myacl_rewrite0 myacl_path0
    acl myacl_rewrite1 hdr(host) -i HOST
    acl myacl_path1 path_dir -i 8090
    acl myacl_referer0 hdr_beg(referer) http://HOST/8090/
    use_backend socket_io_8090 if is_socket_io myacl_referer0
    use_backend mysrv_rewrite1 if myacl_rewrite1 myacl_path1

backend mysrv_rewrite0
    reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /8081/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    server myorigin_rewrite0 127.0.0.1:8081

backend mysrv_rewrite1
    reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /8090/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    server myorigin_rewrite1 127.0.0.1:8090

backend socket_io_8081
    mode http
    option httplog
    # long timeout
    timeout server 86400000
    # check frequently to allow restarting
    # the node backend
    timeout check 1s
    # add X-Forwarded-For
    option forwardfor
    # Do not use httpclose (= client and server
    # connections get closed), since it will close
    # Websockets connections
    no option httpclose
    # Use "option http-server-close" to preserve
    # client persistent connections while handling
    # every incoming request individually, dispatching
    # them one after another to servers, in HTTP close mode
    option http-server-close
    option forceclose
    server node1 127.0.0.1:8081 maxconn 2000 check

backend socket_io_8090
    mode http
    option httplog
    # long timeout
    timeout server 86400000
    # check frequently to allow restarting
    # the node backend
    timeout check 1s
    # add X-Forwarded-For
    option forwardfor
    # Do not use httpclose (= client and server
    # connections get closed), since it will close
    # Websockets connections
    no option httpclose
    # Use "option http-server-close" to preserve
    # client persistent connections while handling
    # every incoming request individually, dispatching
    # them one after another to servers, in HTTP close mode
    option http-server-close
    option forceclose
    server node2 127.0.0.1:8090 maxconn 2000 check
```

Forgot to say, i have

```
socket.io version 0.9.11
haproxy version 1.4.18
```

Comment: I think you need to rename some of your ACLs.  For example, the two ACLs for the node and socket.io WebSockets probably need to be different.  Currently, they're both named ```is_socket_io```.  After you name them something like ```is_node``` and ```is_socket_io```, then you will need to update the relevant use_backend lines to be something like ```use_backend socket_io_8081 if is_node myacl_referer0``` and ```use_backend socket_io_8090 if is_socket_io myacl_referer0```.  That brings me to the myacl_referer0 ACL.  You'll probably need to have two uniquely named ACLs for that one as well.